# Spring initializes differently when run from intellij

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, integration-testing

My desired workflow within intellij is to right click a junit `@Test` annotated method, and choose "run method()".

This is not working right now due to this error: `Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.datasource.url' in string value "${spring.datasource.url}"`

This is happening bc that value, `spring.datasource.url` is not defined in my `application.properties` file, but rather in separate profiles.

My integration test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Api.class)
@IntegrationTest
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "h2")
public class ServiceIntegrationTest {
```

The `application-h2.properties` has `spring.datasource.url` defined.

When I run `mvn test` from the command line, I do not get the error above.

**QUESTIONS:**

- Why are my tests running correctly under maven and not intellij?
- Is intellij overriding the `spring.profiles.active` somehow?
- Is it possible to override active profiles that are set in an `@ActiveProfiles` annotation?

---

**Note**: these are integration tests, but I'm getting the same behavior when running unit tests from intellij.

---

**Edit:**

```
C:\intellij-terminal>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.1 (cab6659f9874fa96462afef40fcf6bc033d58c1c; 2015-03-13T15:10:27-05:00)
Maven home: C:\bin\apache-maven-3.3.1\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\bin\java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

---

**Edit**: Also tried adding `spring.profiles.active=h2` to intellij test run configuration.

---

**Edit:** I noticed intellij starts my tests with this command:

```
C:\bin\java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java  
  -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\dev 
  -Dmaven.home=C:\bin\apache-maven-3.3.1 
  -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\bin\apache-maven-3.3.1\bin\m2.conf 
  -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 
  -classpath 
     C:\bin\apache-maven-3.3.1\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar 
     org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher 
  -Didea.version=14.1.5 
  org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE:run
```

**Questions:**

- Why is intellij trying to run my app?
- Is there a way to tell intellij to use maven commands pointed at a single test?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same version of maven and have the same paths set up? That's the first place I'd like to answer your first question.

Comment: Intellij was using a bundled version 3 of maven. I set intellij to us my local install of maven 3 that my shell is using. Same result.

Comment: What happens when you bring up a terminal in IntelliJ (Alt-F12) and run mvn from the command line?

Comment: Also tried adding spring.profiles.active=h2 to intellij test run configuration.

Comment: Could there be something in your .iml file that is taking precedence? BTW, Kudos for the way you've systematically thought this through.

Comment: Dude, you were on to something. I deleted `.idea/*` and my `iml` file and reimported. That fixed the issue. Sigh. so lame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am glad that deleting the .iml file did the trick.

Another possibility... 
`mvn package -U` followed by File-> Invalidate Caches and Restart.

Answer (score 2):

I deleted `.idea/` and my project's `iml` file and reimported. That fixed the issue.

Comment: You probably don't have the old and new .iml file versions available. But I'm wondering if you figured out what got removed that prevented the profile import from failing.

Comment: Nope, I do not have :(